# Where can I find the indexes to Ein Yaakov online?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, agada-stories-legends

Ein Yaakov, a collection of aggadah from Shas, was originally published with a thematic index and an index according to the parshah, haftarah and megillos. They are described in [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20689531)
[image]

and [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=XAyXRdciBVgC)

[image]

However, looking through the Vilna editions and the ones available on hebrewbooks, I can't find a copy of these indexes which would seem really useful for study. Does anyone know where they can be found, preferably online?

Comment: Have you had a look at Sefaria - https://www.sefaria.org/Ein_Yaakov?tab=contents

Comment: Have you checked the first printing? https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990010966180205171/NLI

Comment: It's not on sefaria but I've found it in the back of the first printing. Thanks! It's still very hard to read though

Comment: I have this set of ein yaakov, newly retypeset - https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/ein-yaakov-7-volume-set-126420.html -- It doesn't have either index. If the vilna edition didn't have it, and this is a reprint of that, then that would explain why it didn't have it. When I read in the introduction that the author was going to make an index, I assumed he didn't manage to do it before he passed away (after the seder of moed). I didn't realize that he had done it.